# Is this valid C scanf?

Tags: c

I know scanf needs an address but does this work?

```
int val;
int *valP = &val;
scanf("%d", valP);
```

My book only shows

```
int val;
scanf("%d", &val);
```

as valid?

Comment: Yes, is valid, `scanf` is expecting a pointer and you are passing a pointer.

Comment: A compiler could answer this question just as well, give it a try!

Comment: @EdwardMoseley: Code that looks like it works could still be undefined behavior. Trying code can only confirm that it doesn't work, not prove that it does.

Comment: Tip: best to check the return value of `scanf()` before subsequently using `val`.  Example: `if (scanf("%d", valP) == 1) printf("%d\n", val);`

Answer (score 8):

**Yes, it is valid**.

`scanf()` expects a pointer to an integer (well, a pointer to the appropriate data type depending on what you've described in the format string) that it can write to (non-const). It doesn't matter *how* you've contrived to give it that pointer, so long as it points to valid memory and is writeable.

In your deviation from the book you've introduced an intermediate step of storing the pointer in a variable and passing that variable in, but otherwise the semantics are completely unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, scanf() needs the address as argument. Reference and pointers both refer to an address. So,

```
scanf("%d",&a)
```

is same as

```
scanf("%d",ptr)
```

where ptr is a pointer to integer.